# Embedding an image to DIscord using Open Graph

Tags: html, discord, share-open-graph

I tried embedding an image to Discord using Open Graph in my website but it keeps looking like [image: this]

Here's what i tried:

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="fiveguys.jpg" property="og:image">
  <meta content="image/png" property="og:image:type">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
```

What I expected (This one just worked a while ago but now it won't):

[image: click for image]